# Software License with an exception?

Tags: licensing

I'm looking for a software License similar to the MIT License (that is, an Opensource software License).

It should cover the following points:

- The software can be used and distributed free of charge;
- The software may be used in opensource and commercial applications;
- The software may be distributed *unaltered* within the application

But with these exceptions:

- The software has to be mentioned in a publicly available document *within* the application (e.g., in the documentation or in the manual);
- The software has to be flagged as such when being altered (and may use a different License in this case)

Does such a License already exist? If not, which license would be a good candidate to insert these exceptions?

Comment: If you're only allowing for unaltered distribution there is very little use in giving the source code in the first place.  Why don't you only give the binary and be done with it?

Comment: @leonm: I believe you misunderstood the concept; The license would protect the unmodified original sources, so nobody may modify them (i.e., by adding vicious code) and redistribute it as the original source. :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own license. The mit license is a template you "can" use, like the others. You can do whatever you want with your intellectual property.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess. I'm going to use the MIT License as template then.

Comment: Don't label it as such. You can tell it is based on the MIT License, but name it EULA (End User License Agreement) or anything you like

Comment: Yes, although EULA sounds so awfully much like what you get with closedsource software if you get the hint ;-)

thanks anyway.